# athlete probability question

Tags: statistics

$60$ athletes participate in a sporting event where the fastest candidate wins. Assuming that completion times are normally distributed with mean $127.23$ seconds and standard deviation $6.74$ seconds, answer the following.

1. Suppose that any athlete finishing the race in under $120$ seconds qualifies for a future event. How many athletes do you expect to qualify?
2. Say an athlete finishes this race in $124.0$ seconds. What is your best approximation for his/her ranking in this event?
3. Predict the maximum completion time for an athlete who wins a medal in this event(i.e, is among the first three to finish the race.)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is an exercise in using the z-score table.

Comment: For #1: From R statistical software (in which `pnorm` is a normal CDF): `pnorm(120, 127.23, 6.74)` returns probability 0.1417. Can you show how to get approximately this value from normal tables? Based on this, how many out of 60 athletes do you expect to have times $\le 120?$ // If you can discuss that much (as part of your question), maybe we can go on to the other two problems.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** Part #3 can be worked approximately by figuring out
what running time will include the fastest 5% of the
60 runners. This method gives a running time of about 116 (maybe a little less, just to be sure). I suppose this is the intended method of solution.

```
qnorm(.05, 127.23, 6.74)
[1] 116.1437

norm(2.5/60, 127.23, 6.74)
[1] 115.5586
```

---

Taking a somewhat different approach, a simulation in R statistical software of 100,000 races, shows that the mean and median running times for the runner in third place (of each race) are 
about 115.7 and 115.8 respectively.

```
t = replicate(10^5, sort(rnorm(60, 127.23, 6.74))[3] )
summary(t)

   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  104.6   114.4   115.8   115.7   117.0   122.8
```